# Aggregation query for @Aggregation annotation in Spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have data saved in mongoDB and I am using Spring Mongo repository to retrieve data from mongoDB. What would the @Aggregation annotation look like if I need to retrieve `average` of data `between start and end timestamp` , groupBy `seriesId` ? I tried below annotation

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$match:{'timestamp' : { $gte: ?1, $lte: ?2 }}}","{$group:{ _id: {'seriesId':$seriesId}, average: { $avg: $value }}}"})
List<Series> findAllByDate(String p1, ZonedDateTime from, ZonedDateTime to );
```

but it throws me an error `The field 'series_id' must be an accumulator object`

My data looks like this;

```
[
  {
    "id": "5fa1bad3d054121ce66727c7",
    "seriesId": "1",
    "buildingName": "testBuilding",
    "value": 3,
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T01:00:00+01:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "5fa1bad3d054121ce66727c8",
    "seriesId": "1",
    "buildingName": "testBuilding",
    "value": 2,
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T02:00:00+01:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "5fa1bad3d054121ce66727c9",
    "seriesId": "1",
    "buildingName": "testBuilding",
    "value": 1,
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T03:00:00+01:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "5fa1bad3d054121ce66727ca",
    "seriesId": "1",
    "buildingName": "testBuilding",
    "value": 0,
    "timestamp": "2020-01-01T04:00:00+01:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) - see the syntax.

Comment: My corrected query after matching with the syntax gives me 
```[
  {
    "id": null,
    "seriesId": null,
    "buildingName": null,
    "value": null,
    "timestamp": null
  }
]``` - what I would like to achieve is, `[ {seriesId: 1, average:49}, {seriesId:2, average: 500},...]` would appreciate any help!

Comment: latest query updated in above question...

Comment: In `{ $gte: ?1, $lte: ?2 }`, the parameter replacement placeholders should be `{ $gte: '?0', $lte: '?1' }`. The placeholders start from `0`.

Comment: Still my bad, I modified the code for stackoverflow, the params are infact 2(index1)nd and 3rd(index2) places, I changed the code to reflect the scenario

Answer (score 2):

Finally this is the query that worked for me;

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$match:{'timestamp' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 }}}","{$group:{ _id: '$series_id', average: { $avg: '$value' }}}"})
List<TimeseriesAvg> findAvgBySeries(ZonedDateTime from, ZonedDateTime to );
```

I found that the best way is to run your aggregation query directly on mongo cli and then using `@aggregation` annotation, query transformation will be done as above.

This is the query that works in mongo cli for above `@aggregation` annotation of Spring

```
db.timeseries.aggregate(pipeline = {$match:{'timestamp' : { $gte:ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") , $lte:ISODate("2020-01-05T00:00:00Z") }}}, {$group:{ _id: '$series_id', average: { $avg: '$value' }}})
```